# How can I forward all traffic from one of a VPS's 2 IPs to my home computer using Wireguard?

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, nat

I am trying to wean myself off the big companies, and would like to get a home server up and running with Nextcloud and a mail server. I know how to use dynamic DNS and whatnot, but for mail you need a static IP, not just a domain name, which is not an option with my ISP. My idea, then, is to get a VPS with a static IP, and use a VPN to connect it with my home server (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS). I would forward all incoming traffic to one IP to my home server, and use the other IP to SSH in for management, etc.

The point of this is to have a "static IP" to the outside world that I can use in the same way I could use it if my home internet connection had a static IP address.

Here's where I am:

- I have purchased a KVM VPS plan with Dedipath that has two static
  IPs. It runs Ubuntu 20.04.
- I have a home server running Ubuntu 20.04.
- I have successfully set up a Wireguard connection between the home server and the VPS using VPN, and have confirmed that the home server can only reach the internet through the VPN (my home LAN is also still accessible from it, and needs to stay that way).
- I own a domain name for which I can point the DNS to whatever IP address I
  want.

What I cannot figure out is what cryptic commands I need to use in iptables or UFW (I'd prefer UFW, I guess, but I don't really care which) to get it to do this. I have literally been searching for months without finding the answer, and I guess my brain just does not work right to figure out the syntax here by myself.

I would really appreciate some help if anyone has it. Thanks!